# Rotating IP with selenium and Tor

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I have a selenium configuration for **scraping** a specific HTTP request, this request was send only when I click on a specific REACT element of a website.
That's the reason why i'm using selenium... can't find other way.

I must renew my IP, each time I want to **scrape** this specific HTTP request.
For achieve this I use Tor.
When I start my python script it works very well, Tor set a new ip and scrape what I want.
I have add a try/catch to my script, if my script can't work the first time, it will retry 10 times.

The problem is when my script try another time, the IP can't rotate anymore....

how achieve this ?

```py
import time
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import os
import subprocess
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent



options_wire = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://localhost:8088',
        'https': 'https://localhost:8088',
        'no_proxy': ''
    }
}

def firefox_init():
    os.system("killall tor")
    time.sleep(1)
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    subprocess.Popen(("tor --HTTPTunnelPort 8088"),shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    return user_agent


def profile_firefox():
    profile = FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
    profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", firefox_init())
    profile.set_preference("driver.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
    profile.update_preferences()
    return profile



def options_firefox():
    options = Options()
    options.headless = False
    return options


def firefox_closing(driver):
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system('killall tor')
      


def headless(url):
    for x in range(0, 10):
        profile = profile_firefox()
        options = options_firefox()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options_wire,firefox_profile=profile, options=options, executable_path='******/headless_browser/geckodriver')
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(randint(1024, 2060), randint(1024, 4100))
        # time.sleep(randint(3,10))
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(randint(3,8))
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"*******\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button"):
                # driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"*******\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
                # time.sleep(randint(8,10))
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"*******\"]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/button").click()
                time.sleep(randint(3,6))
                for request in driver.requests:
                    if request.path == "https://api.*********.***/*******/*********":
                        request_api = request
                        raw = str(request_api.body)
                        request_api = raw.split(('b\''))
                        payload_raw = request_api[1]
                        payload = payload_raw[:-1]
                        if payload:
                            header = request.headers
                            print(header, payload)
                            break
                else:
                    continue
                break
    
        except:
            firefox_closing(driver)
            time.sleep(5)
        finally:
            firefox_closing(driver)

            
    return header, payload


url="https://check.torproject.org/?lang=fr"
headless(url)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to achieve this, I use an other proxy, selenium-wire is very good but it need to be fix.

I have use Browsermob proxy and set an upstream proxy to work with.
The result is you can catch every HTTP resquest or response parse it and the ip rotate every time and use tor HTTPTunnelPort configuration.

```py
    proxy_params = {'httpProxy': 'localhost:8088', 'httpsProxy': 'localhost:8088'}
    proxy_b = server.create_proxy(params=proxy_params)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't possibly know how it's not renewing the IP address since you kill the tor process. Even if you put tor as a service in Systemd, it'd renew as you restart the service, certainly. But I might give you some directions:

- On the fake agent module, try to disable cache to avoid caching in the /tmp directory or using hosted cache server:

```py
    ua = UserAgent(cache=False, use_cache_server=False)
```

- Put Tor on systemd and avoid using os.system(), it's not secure and it's open to lots of flaws as you input system commands directly on your script. And with the service file, you might just restart the service to renew your IP address. You might want to use the Arch Linux Wiki reference to configure your own TOR environment in [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tor)!

Comment: Thanks Carlos for your answer.
In my multiple test, I thinks the issue is in the seleniumwire package itself.
When I import the official selenium webdriver, Tor can renew the IP each time and selenium use the new IP every time.
I'm looking in the package if the connection is closed when the webdriver is kill.

Comment: In fake-useragent v1.2.1 getting "Unexpected keyword argument 'cache' in constructor call" and "Unexpected keyword argument 'use_cache_server' in constructor call" with the code above.